# Can I store resources and Windows Forms in a Visual Studio Shared Project?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, managed, shared-project

I've got `ProjectA`.  It has a WinForm and some `.resx` files in it.  I created a Shared Project (`ProjectA-shared`) and moved everything to it.  `ProjectA` references `ProjectA-shared`.

When I compile the Solution with VS2013 and the Shared Project plug-in,  I get the following exception when running the app:

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or
>   the neutral culture.  Make sure "Foo.Controls.MyForm.resources" was
>   correctly embedded or linked into assembly "Foo" at compile time, or
>   that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully
>   signed.

When I compile the Solution with VS2015, everything is OK.

I am now left wondering:

1. Why would there be a difference between the VS2013 and VS2015 outputs?
2. It looks like `.resx` and WinForms aren't a natural fit for 'Shared Projects':  what is the best way to share this kind of thing between two projects (primarily, projects using Shared Project just so that they can target .NET 4 and 4.5)